# How to select distinct from a geojson column?

Tags: postgresql

I have over 10,000 geojson rows in a pgsql table and i would like to know how do i go about selecting only distinct coordinates?

Here is a snippet of the geojson column in pgsql:

```
"{"type":"Point","coordinates":[40.7245597839355,-73.9956512451172]}"
"{"type":"Point","coordinates":[40.7349281311035,-73.9920043945312]}"
"{"type":"Point","coordinates":[40.725212097168,-73.9776840209961]}"
"{"type":"Point","coordinates":[40.7429084777832,-73.9770584106445]}"
"{"type":"Point","coordinates":[40.7393226623535,-74.0081176757812]}"
```

Comment: The snippet is only a GeoJSON fragment. What does the whole document look like? Don't need all the details, but at least the main parts of the document, like where the snippet is located in the document. In particular, does every row in your table have multiple fragments with coordinates or just a single one? Do you use the PostGIS extension? Please provide more detail because as it is now it is impossible to give a proper answer.

Comment: It's not a document, its a pgsql table. I am unable to put 10,000+ records on this forum.

Comment: Show the `create table` statement and output of `select * from table_name limit 1;`

Comment: You should first get your terminology right. With "over 10,000 geojson rows in a pgsql table" you probably mean that you have a table in a PostgreSQL database which has a field with `json` (`jsonb`?) data type containing a document in GeoJSON format. The table has more than 10,000 rows. Now back to my first comment. If the code you post is from 5 rows and each is the total content (and therefore _not_ a snippet), then the enclosing outer quotes should be single. If it _is a snippet_ then show us what other parts there are to the total document (a JSON "object" is called a document).

Comment: Please also indicate your PostgreSQL version. There are major changes in JSON support in recent versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any problems

```
select distinct
json_field #>> '{coordinates, 0}' as latitude,
json_field #>> '{coordinates, 1}' as longitude
from some_table;
```

Comment: And what if the `json_field` has multiple coordinates? What if it is buried deeper into the document?

Comment: @Patrick there is nothing about it in the question. Even so, it's not difficult to rewrite selector.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But i get  *"{c" <-- parse error at position 2 within geometry*